# Swift 5 Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am getting the following error on the first line of this code:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

```swift
@objc static func makeShareLink( _ type: String, id: Int? = nil) -> String {
}
```

This class declaration is

```swift
@objc class Util: NSObject {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot represent an optional `Int` exposed to Objective C.

This will work:

```
@objc static func makeShareLink( _ type: String, id: Int) -> String {
    ...
}
```

If you want to use an optional number that can be exposed to Objective-C, this will work:

```
@objc static func makeShareLink( _ type: String, id: NSNumber? = nil) -> String {
    ...
}
```

The reason this works is because `NSNumber` is an *object* that can be `nil`, but an `Int` is not represented as an object in Objective C, but as a *value*.

Comment: Can't @objc func  use Option parameter?

Comment: Please see edit.